# Why dlsym returns a PLT entry for a non-pie executable?

Tags: linux, binary, linker, symbols, elf

I have a non-pie (this whole explanation only happens with non-pie executables) binary that has undefined symbols for `malloc`:

```
$ nm python3.8 -D | grep malloc
                 U malloc
```

and indeed, `malloc` has a relocation in the PLT:

````
$ readelf -r python3.8 | grep malloc
000000aaf310  03b900000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000422e00 malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0```
````

This is corroborated by checking the PLT itself:

```
$ objdump -d -j .plt python3.8  | grep malloc -C 2
0000000000422e00 <malloc@plt>:
  422e00:       ff 25 0a c5 68 00       jmpq   *0x68c50a(%rip)        # aaf310 <malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5>
  422e06:       68 5f 00 00 00          pushq  $0x5f
  422e0b:       e9 f0 f9 ff ff          jmpq   422800 <_init@@Base+0x20>
```

When executing `dlsym(NULL, "malloc")` inside a shared library that is dlopen-ed by the binary (with gdb, for easy reading of the result) I get:

```
(gdb) p dlsym(0, "malloc")
$1 = (void *) 0x422e00 <malloc@plt>
```

**How is this possible? My understanding is that `dlsym` should return the `malloc` symbol address and not a PLT entry.**

I noticed also this weird thing: Executing the binary under `LD_DEBUG=all` shows the following:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=all python3.8 -c "pass"  -vvvvv |& grep malloc
      6435:     symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=python3.8 [0]
      6435:     binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to python3.8 [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
      6435:     symbol=__malloc_initialize_hook;  lookup in file=python3.8 [0]
      6435:     symbol=__malloc_initialize_hook;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
      6435:     binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__malloc_initialize_hook' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
      6435:     symbol=__malloc_hook;  lookup in file=python3.8 [0]
      6435:     symbol=__malloc_hook;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
      6435:     binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__malloc_hook' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
      6435:     symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=python3.8 [0]
      6435:     binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 [0] to python3.8 [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
      6435:     symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=python3.8 [0]
      6435:     symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
      6435:     binding file /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
      6435:     symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=python3.8 [0]
      6435:     symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
      6435:     binding file python3.8 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

For some reason, the linker is binding `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` to `python3.8` for the `malloc` symbol (`binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to python3.8 [0]: normal symbol malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]`) when this should be the other way around. Later, this is actually reversed when we can see `binding file python3.8 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]`.

In my particular case with the shared library, the linker also shows:

```
      6496:     binding file my_shared_library.so [0] to python3.8 [0]: normal symbol `malloc' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

I expected that to be linking against `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` (where `malloc` lives), not against `python3.8`.

**How can the linker decide to bind against `python3.8` for the `malloc` symbol when we have seen that the library does not define it?**

If you want to reproduce this, you can use a docker container with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and the python3.8 package.

Comment: (Is this an actual problem, or just a hobby-project? I think the term is _implementation detail_ meaning it can be changed without notice.)

Comment: This is an actual problem. What is here the *implementation detail* you are referring to?

Comment: Well `dlsym(NULL,"malloc")` might return any address (PLT or not), provided you can use it to access the functionality of `malloc`. (Word `PLT` isn't used at all in the manual of `malloc`.)

Comment: I understand that, but the address in the PLT is an undefined symbol in the binary as indicated in the text. Also `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"malloc")` returns `NULL` as if the `libc` symbol cannot be seen, which I also don't understand.